# Change Label color on radio selected from css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change the text for color of a `Span` if a radio button is checked through css. Below is my code:

```
<div class="div-box-content">
    <label data-ng-repeat="addType in addressFormatOptions">
        <input name="nameAddressType"
               type="radio"
               class="radio"
               value="{{ addType }}"
               ng-model="exportLablesUserParams.addressFormat" />
            <span></span> {{  addType   }}
     </label>
</div>
```

css are as :

```
.div-box-content {
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #696969;
}    

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: green;
}

label > input[type=radio]:checked {
    color: green !important;
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

I am not understanding what mistake i am doing. Please check the css and my code and let me know about my mistake and if possible please correct it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: either give us the generated HTML or provide us a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can not style the label since it is a parent of the checked radio button.  You will need to restructure your HTML in a different way or use JS to change the color on change of the radio button.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, basically in my code you can see <span></span> {{  addType   }} line. these value are coming dynamically and i want to change the color of this if radio button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stated HTML and requirement to change the `span` color and not the `label`...

```
label > input[type=radio]:checked + span {
    color: yourcolorhere;

}
```